# The imported project was not found

Tags: database, visual-studio

When I open the .sln file of a certain project using the Visual Studio, I get a msg like that attached in the link saying

**" The imported project "C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.targets"**

was not found while it opens smoothly with my partners, what is the problem & what should I do?

Comment: If you do a web search on that exact message you will see lots of relevant hits.

Comment: I did for a fair amount of time, perused many techniques and eventually got nothing

Comment: Yes, but you didn't tell _us_ that. How do those refs not apply? It's about showing your research as per [ask]. I mean, did you even check to see if that project is present at the location specified?

Comment: Yeah, it exists

Comment: Also there was a suggestion to change a certain line in the .csproj file, but the problem was still there

Comment: See, you need to _tell_ us what you've tried, because no one, including myself, wants to ask a question and be told "yeah, already did that." Help us help you.

Comment: Yes, you are right I'm sorry,
I also tried to shorten the path of the sln file

That is all for what I could understand and try from the results I found

Comment: I bet if you ran VS as admin it'll work.